# SQL Server SSIS quandary

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS job that generates a list of servers from a table, then executes a stored procedure located in an administrative database on each server.

When I try to add one specific server to the list table, it fails trying to set the connection manager for the new server, with the message below.

There is nothing to be found in the SQL Server Error Log, nor in the Event Viewer on either the the server running the job or the one I'm attempting to add.

> Executed as user: CORPORATE\SqlagentPRD. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
>     Version 12.0.5000.0 for 32-bit
>     Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Started:
>     2:40:56 PM
>     Error: 2018-09-26 14:40:58.24
>
> Code: 0xC0209302
>
> Source: SQL Server Log Consolidation Connection manager "SourceQuery"
>
> Description: The requested OLE DB provider SQLCNLI11.0 is not registered. If the 32-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 64-bit mode. Error code: 0x00000000.
>     An OLE DB record is available.
>     Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"
>     Hresult: 0x80040154
>     Description: "Class not registered".
>     End Error
>     Error: 2018-09-26 14:40:58.24
>
> Code: 0xC020801C
>
> Source: Data Flow Task OLE DB Source [30]
>
> Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.
>     The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "SourceQuery" failed with error code 0xC0209302.
>     There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
>     End Error
>     Error: 2018-09-26 14:40:58.24
>
> Code: 0xC0047017
>
> Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline
>
> Description: OLE DB Source failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.
>     End Error
>     Error: 2018-09-26 14:40:58.24
>
> Code: 0xC004700C
>
> Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline
>
> Description: One or more component failed validation.
>     End Error
>     Error: 2018-09-26 14:40:58.24
>
> Code: 0xC0024107
>
> Source: Data Flow Task
>
> Description: There were errors during task validation.
>     End Error
>     DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
>     Started:
>     2:40:56 PM
>     Finished: 2:40:58 PM
>     Elapsed:
>     1.657 seconds.
>     The package execution failed.
>     The step failed.

Comment: Are all your SQL Servers the same version? What version is the new one that isn't working?

Comment: Are you may be connecting to a different version of SQL Server, for which the provider is not installed on the SSIS server?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a typo issue. The provider is SQL**NCLI**, not SQL**CNLI**